# geo Django: get the neighbors of a house

Tags: python, django, gis, geo, geodjango

i have a house model with these properties

```
centerpoint = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
front_left = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
front_right = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
rear_left = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
rear_right = PointField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
polygon = PolygonField(srid=0, null=True, blank=True)
direction = FloatField(null=True, blank=True)  # the direction this house faces, in degrees
```

and i want to get the houses in front of a specific house... im having a hard time trying to use Distance and polygon__dwithin

i need to get the ones that are touching and the ones that have relative direction of less than 160 degrees:

for that i do:

```
House.objects.filter(polygon__touches=house_instance.polygon, direction__lt=160)
```

how can i modify this query to get the houses that are in front maximum one block and the ones that are one house away from my reference house?

EDIT:
so "facing direction" its actually the direction field that contains in degrees the direction the house is facing by the front door

and this is an image of what i need in term of neighbors,

my polygon field its the actual "area" of the house in points...

sorry if my terminology is wacky im very new at this...

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "facing direction"? How do you define "in front"?

Comment: Please post a sample of house polygons (preferably in geojson), marking the reference house and the target houses.

Comment: i updated my question @Udi

Comment: I have posted some advice.  If you can upload the houses' and the streets' polygons, I can try sending some queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also hold the polygons (or even lines) of the streets, you can query for the street facing the house, and then query which houses face this street.

A cool workaround could be using reverse geocoding (for example, by google maps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) to retrieve the house's street address and later the street addresses of the other houses and try matching them.  This would work only if the reverse geocoding service possess this data for your area and is accurate enough.